# Filtering the array of an observable object that's being filtered TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I feel like this is hard to explain but I'm passing observables from my generic db service to my components.

The methods look like this:

```
getCollectionThroughDivisionId(id: UUID): Observable<T[]> {
    return this._table.watch().map(returnedObjects => 
        returnedObjects.filter(returnedObject => returnedObject.divisionId == id)
    );
}
```

The above method returns an observable array of a generic object, filtered through its divisionId

The things is I need a method that filters an array inside the returnedObject for an id

```
getCollectionThroughUserId(id: UUID): Observable<T[]> {
    return this._table.watch().map(returnedObjects => 
        returnedObjects.filter(returnedObject => returnedObject.userId.filter(x => x == id))
    );
}
```

The parameter userId is an array of id's, but that defaults to returning the entire collection (without throwing an error).

edit:

The object model:

```
export class Task {
    id: string;
    name: string;

    userId: string[];
    projectId: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<ITask>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

Json example:

```
{
"id":  "TA18XVBJ3584ZM3" ,
"name":  "User documentation & technical documentation" ,
"projectId":  "PRYH3C72C6CQKZS" ,
"userId": [
    "USGC6W4RCERY2ET",
    "USKWQYHKB8E3X2U"
    ]
}
```

The goal: iterate over every Task, check the userId array if it contains the passed userId

Comment: filter is probably not the right method to use here you should probably use map instead in order to map the returnedObjects to objects where that have fewer userIDs. :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, I need to check every userId in every object. Any chance you could give me an example?

Comment: just to get this straight. What you want to do is filter out user ids from the returnedObject.userId property. If you have { userId: [1,2] } and id = 1, you should get back {userId: [1] } ?

Comment: it would be useful if you could give us an example data set and how you want it transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that it sounds like you getting data from the server that you shouldn't be allowed to see (usually filtering out stuff the user shouldn't see it's the backends job).

All you really need to do is return whether the **id** is in the objects list of **userIds**.

```js
getCollectionThroughUserId(id: UUID): Observable<T[]> {
    return this._table.watch().map(returnedObjects => 
        returnedObjects.filter(returnedObject => returnedObject.userId.indexOf(id) !== -1)
    );
}
```

This will remove from the list any returnedObject which does not have the **id** in the **userId** list.

Comment: are you sure userId is not null instead? if it's an empty list it should be fine. Can you post the error you get?

Comment: Going to delete my comment, your code works fine. Thanks for the help!